# How to delete a Node from a Nokogiri Nodeset?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, node-set

I have a nodeset in the variable `my_nodeset`

I'd like to remove the last node that was found.

Initially i expected this to work: `my_nodeset.last.remove` but it does not.

The only way I've found to remove the last item is with something like this:
`my_nodeset.delete(my_nodeset.last)`

Seems strange to me and i was wondering if there's a "correct" way to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not strange to me.

`my_nodeset.last.remove` means:

call `Nodeset` my_nodeset then go to its last `Node` member and call `remove` method (owned by last). You want to ask to a `Node` method to modify a `NodeSet`. That's semantically wrong to me.

`my_nodeset.delete(my_nodeset.last)` is how it should be.

Comment: dierre makes complete sense when you put it like that.  Thank you!